# Using QEventLoop to call a function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have two Button: play and pause. And I slider bar.

I want to press the player to change the position of the slide until an event is issued, or the pause button is pressed. For this reason I'm using QEventLoop.

```
void MainWindow::slider()
{

  for(min_value = ui->horizontalSlide->value(); min_value <= max_value; min_value++){
     //msleep(2000);
     ui->horizontalSlide->setValue(min_value);
  }
}


void MainWindow::on_playButton_clicked()
{
     QEventLoop loop2;
     QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(quitLoop()), &loop2... ?);
     loop2.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_pauseButton_clicked()
{
     emit quitLoop();

}
```

But I'm not sure how to connect the QEventLoop to the on_playButton_clicked function.... Any examples or advice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not a simple QTimer to update the slider and a signal to start and another one to stop the timer ?

Comment: @Marco As the slider changes, a function is called to draw on the screen. Therefore the slider can only change position when the drawing is finished.

Can I do this using QTimer?

Comment: Yes you can, you can connect the QTimer signal to the first drawing function and when that is over you emit a signal to move the slider.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try using QTimer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to create an eventLoop for this case, just use a QTimer:

***.h**

```
private:    
    QTimer *timer
```

**.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    :QMainWindow(parent)
{
    [...]
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this](){
         int value = ui->horizontalSlide->value();
         ui->horizontalSlide->setValue(value+1);
         if(ui->horizontalSlide->value() == ui->horizontalSlide->maximum())
             timer->stop();
    });
}

void MainWindow::on_playButton_clicked(){

    timer->start(2000);
}


void MainWindow::on_pauseButton_clicked()
{
     timer->stop();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.